# Update Access Tables with Data entered in forms

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I have created a form to search for a record based on user input. user searches for a Site using SiteID which he enters and clicks okay. Which opens up another form with all the details for the site. User can then make changes to the Site details in this form and when he presses enter button it should update the table with all the changes made. Changes could be one text box or several text boxes.

I wrote a query but it is throwing error:

```
    Private Sub Enter_Click()
          SQL = "UPDATE Tracker " _
          & " SET Tracker.[Site ID] = " & Me.[Site ID] _
          & " , Tracker.[EHR Vendor] = " & Me.[EHR Vendor] _
          & " , Tracker.[Site Name] = " & Me.[Site Name] _
          & " WHERE Tracker.[Site ID] = " & Me.[Site ID] & ";"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    End Sub
```

Is this the best way to proceed or is there another method I can follow.

Comment: I am getting Run-Time error '3075': Syntax Error (Missing operator) in query expression 'Test 123'. 'Test 123' is the site name in this query

Comment: Figured it out. Used Me.Refresh to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a form, let’s call it subtracker, that contains all of the fields in the tracker table. Then in design view of the form where the user selects the siteID I add the subtracker form as a sub form and link the siteID field on the sub form to the selection box on the main form. Adding a sub form is an option on the design tab

Comment: Thanks pmorgan. Let me try that. However, got it to work with Me.Refresh